# Entity Framework - how to retrieve only one record from bridge table and delete it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have two tables connected as many-to-many relationship in EF.
Let's assume, that I have table "Person" & "Groups".
What I want to achieve is to delete only one group from specified Person. 
I dont want to delete either Person nor Group, just the record in Bridge Table.
How to do that?
Is there a need to include "auto-generated" bridge table in DBContext?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to a Bridge table as a Cross reference table for example Person_Group which contains id from Person and id/s from Group ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using EF 6 Code first configure your entities to be many to many as described in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_4) (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for the classes and relationships).  If you're working with a Person entity, then you would remove the group in question from the entities Groups collection, then save the entity.  If you're working with a Group, you would remove the Person from the entities People collection and save.